# Javax: ErrorListener not called when transforming a fo file into a pdf

Tags: java, xslt, error-handling, saxon, apache-fop

I'm working on a Servlet which utilizes Apache FOP.

Input .fo files are converted to PDF files. Some input files references
external images; if these are not available, the transformer gives
messages like this:

```
07.07.2013 22:53:01 org.apache.fop.fo.flow.ExternalGraphic bind
SCHWERWIEGEND: Image not available: sunset.jpg
```

To handle such cases, I have implemented an ErrorListener:

```
import javax.xml.transform.ErrorListener;

class MyErrorListener implements ErrorListener {
    int warnings;
    int fatals;
    int errors;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    public void warning(TransformerException e) throws TransformerException {
        warnings++;
        sb.append(e.getMessageAndLocation() + "\n");;
    }

    @Override
    public void fatalError(TransformerException e)
            throws TransformerException {
        fatals++;
        sb.append(e.getMessageAndLocation() + "\n");;
    }

    @Override
    public void error(TransformerException e) throws TransformerException {
        errors++;
        sb.append(e.getMessageAndLocation() + "\n");;
    }

    String getMessages() {
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

An instance of this class is attached to the transformer, just before the transformation is started:

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
MyErrorListener el = new MyErrorListener();
transformer.setErrorListener(el);
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(tempFile2),
    new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler()));
```

But instead of calling any of the implemented error, warning or fatalError methods
of the listener, the transformer keeps on reporting the errors to stderr.

I even tried to attach the listener to the factory:

```
tFactory.setErrorListener(el);
```

but with no success.

Any idea what is wrong with my code? Or is a missing image below the reporting level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming from the XSL-FO processor, not the XSLT processor. Saxon knows about your ErrorListener, but it doesn't know about the error. FOP knows about the error, but it doesn't know about the ErrorListener.

Comment: I see. Based on this new insight, I found a solution:
1. implement a org.apache.fop.events.EventListener
2. attach it to the FoUserAgent event broadcaster like that: foUserAgent.getEventBroadcaster().addEventListener(fel);